# java/jackson - chained @JsonValue annotations and deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have the following construction. I know it seems odd, but I am simulating our code with this example:

```
public static class StringWrapper {
    protected final String s;

    @JsonValue
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public StringWrapper(final String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public static class StringWrapperOuter {
    protected final StringWrapper s;

    @JsonValue
    public StringWrapper getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public StringWrapperOuter(final StringWrapper s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public static class POJO {
    protected final List<StringWrapperOuter> data;

    public List<StringWrapperOuter> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public POJO(final List<StringWrapperOuter> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public POJO() {
        data = Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Serialization of the POJO gives the expected JSON array of strings:

```
<mapper>.writeValue(System.out, new POJO(Arrays.asList(new StringWrapperOuter(new StringWrapper("a")), new StringWrapperOuter(new StringWrapper("b")), new StringWrapperOuter(new StringWrapper("c")))));

{"data":["a","b","c"]}
```

How can I deserialize this JSON string into an object of type POJO?

```
<mapper>.readValue("{\"data\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}", POJO.class);
```

The mapper has difficulties to recognize the input, since two `@JsonValue` annotations are chained. It gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class StringWrapperOuter] from String value ('a'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: {"data":["a","b","c"]}; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: POJO["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@JsonValue` is for serializing. The analogous annotation for deserializing is `@JsonCreator`.

Annotate your constructors

```
@JsonCreator
public StringWrapper(final String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
```

and

```
@JsonCreator
public StringWrapperOuter(final StringWrapper s) {
    this.s = s;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As Sotirios said in a previous answer. The `@JsonCreator` is the key here. But, in order to get all of the classes to work `@JsonProperty` might be needed.

```
public static class POJO {
    protected final List<StringWrapperOuter> data;

    // In order for POJO creation to work properly the @JsonProperty
    // annotation on the arg is required
    @JsonCreator
    public POJO(@JsonProperty("data") final List<StringWrapperOuter> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<StringWrapperOuter> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public static class StringWrapper {
    protected final String s;

    @JsonCreator
    public StringWrapper(final String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
}

public static class StringWrapperOuter {
    protected final StringWrapper s;

    @JsonCreator
    public StringWrapperOuter(final StringWrapper s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public StringWrapper getS() {
        return s;
    }
}
```